Can I use an Artistic License 2.0 library in a MIT License library
I have a library licensed under the MIT License.
Recently, one of the dependencies of my library, that I use unchanged, switched from the MIT License to The Artistic License 2.0.
Am I still able to update to new versions of that dependency, or do I need to fork it?

(1) Do you plan to modify the software that's licensed under the Artistic License 2.0? (2) Is your software that is using these dependent software, proprietary or open source? If open source, under which license?

@ruben2020 (1) No (2) My software is a library licensed under MIT License

The Artistic License 2.0 has some strict requirements when you make changes to the code, but it has very few restrictions if you just use the package that was distributed under the Artistic License.
There are two clauses from the Artistic License that are most relevant for your use case:

(8) You are permitted to link Modified and Standard Versions with
other works, to embed the Package in a larger work of your own, or to
build stand-alone binary or bytecode versions of applications that
include the Package, and Distribute the result without restriction,
provided the result does not expose a direct interface to the Package.

This essentially states that as long as your library is not a simple wrapper, but provides a different kind of functionality, then you are completely free in your choice of license.

(5)  You may Distribute Compiled forms of the Standard Version without
the Source, provided that you include complete instructions on how to
get the Source of the Standard Version.  Such instructions must be
valid at the time of your distribution.  If these instructions, at any
time while you are carrying out such distribution, become invalid, you
must provide new instructions on demand or cease further distribution.
If you provide valid instructions or cease distribution within thirty
days after you become aware that the instructions are invalid, then
you do not forfeit any of your rights under this license.

If you (or one of your users) distribute a binary that is (statically) linked to the Artistic Licensed package, then that distribution must include instructions for how to obtain the source code for that package and keep those instructions up-to-date.
There is no requirement for other source code or being able to replace the package with a different version.
